# maximize the number of $k$-intersection via $n$ lines

Tags: combinatorics

Consider $n$ lines $l_1,l_2, \ldots, l_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We call a point $P \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is a $k$-intersection if $P$ lies in at least $k$ lines.

A simple counting argument yield the number of $k$-intersection is $O\left(\frac{n^2}{(k-1)^2}\right)$. I would like to ask if this upper bound is achievable (for example, is it possible to construct an instance with $\Theta(n)$ $\sqrt{n}$-intersections).